# Organising Factor Variables Prior to GLM fit in R

Tags: r, function

I do a lot of work with GLMs in R, on quite large data sets (often including dozens of variables in a model fit). In order to be able to produce graphical output of a certain kind after I've fitted a model, I find it useful to "prepare" any variable that I intend to fit as a factor (those whose names begin with `f_` below) before the model fit. By this I mean:

(i) because I reorder each factor before fitting a GLM such that the reference level is equal to the level with the most weight, I want to preserve the level ordering prior to the `relevel()` command;

(ii) in order to highlight the reference level in graphs later, I like to keep a record of it in a separate variable.

I've put an example together of this approach using the built-in `mtcars` dataset.

Currently I have this code:

```
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

# tidy up and make easier to read

df <- mtcars # built in data set

# let's make it a bit easier to follow

df <- df %>%
  select(mpg,
         f_cylinders = cyl,
         c_displacement = disp,
         c_hp = hp,
         c_final_drive_ratio = drat,
         c_weight = wt,
         c_qtr_mile_time = qsec,
         f_v_or_straight = vs,
         f_transmission = am,
         f_gears = gear,
         f_num_carbs = carb)

df$f_v_or_straight <- ifelse(df$f_v_or_straight == 0, "V", "Straight")
df$f_transmission <- ifelse(df$f_transmission == 0, "Automatic", "Manual")

df$glm_weight <- 1

# organise factors - levels, reference level, weights

my_list <- list()

df$f_cylinders <- as.factor(df$f_cylinders)
my_list$f_cylinders_levels <- levels(df$f_cylinders) 
my_list$f_cylinders_weights <- df %>% group_by(f_cylinders) %>% summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) %>% ungroup() %>% pull(glm_weight)
my_list$f_cylinders_ref <- "8"
df$f_cylinders <- df$f_cylinders %>% relevel(ref = my_list$f_cylinders_ref)

df$f_v_or_straight <- as.factor(df$f_v_or_straight)
my_list$f_v_or_straight_levels <- levels(df$f_v_or_straight) 
my_list$f_v_or_straight_weights <- df %>% group_by(f_v_or_straight) %>% summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) %>% ungroup() %>% pull(glm_weight)
my_list$f_v_or_straight_ref <- "V"
df$f_v_or_straight <- df$f_v_or_straight %>% relevel(ref = my_list$f_v_or_straight_ref)

df$f_transmission <- as.factor(df$f_transmission)
my_list$f_transmission_levels <- levels(df$f_transmission) 
my_list$f_transmission_weights <- df %>% group_by(f_transmission) %>% summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) %>% ungroup() %>% pull(glm_weight)
my_list$f_transmission_ref <- "Automatic"
df$f_transmission <- df$f_transmission %>% relevel(ref = my_list$f_transmission_ref)

df$f_gears <- as.factor(df$f_gears)
my_list$f_gears_levels <- levels(df$f_gears) 
my_list$f_gears_weights <- df %>% group_by(f_gears) %>% summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) %>% ungroup() %>% pull(glm_weight)
my_list$f_gears_ref <- "3"
df$f_gears <- df$f_gears %>% relevel(ref = my_list$f_gears_ref)

df$f_num_carbs <- as.factor(df$f_num_carbs)
my_list$f_num_carbs_levels <- levels(df$f_num_carbs) 
my_list$f_num_carbs_weights <- df %>% group_by(f_num_carbs) %>% summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) %>% ungroup() %>% pull(glm_weight)
my_list$f_num_carbs_ref <- "4"
df$f_num_carbs <- df$f_num_carbs %>% relevel(ref = my_list$f_num_carbs_ref)
```

This code works fine, but...in real world uses I'm dealing with dozens of factor variables, not just the 5 above. So if I've got 50 factor variables, I'm doing the same thing 50 times over. I'd like to bundle this preparation into a single function call, essentially saying:

For each field whose name starts with `f_` (ie looks like `f_xxx`):

1. turn it from `chr`/`int`/whatever into a factor `f_xxx`;
2. work out weights `f_xxx_weights`
3. work out reference level `f_xxx_ref` (unsure what to do if there's a tie for the lead);
4. store the current factor levels in  `f_xxx_levels`;
5. rearrange factor levels so that `f_xxx_ref` is the first in the list.

I'm asking quite a lot here...but anything to nudge me forward a little would be most gratefully received.

Thank you.

Comment: No do you calculate *weight*? Or is this same as highest frequency? If so, why not reorder factor levels by decreasing frequency?

Comment: In this case I'm using equal weights, so I could use summarise(glm_weight = n()) instead of summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) - but in general my weights won't be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Consider generalizing your `relevel` process in a user-defined method and then map through the `f_` columns calling your process using `purrr::map_df` (to be consistent with tidy):

**Data**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg,
         f_cylinders = cyl,
         c_displacement = disp,
         c_hp = hp,
         c_final_drive_ratio = drat,
         c_weight = wt,
         c_qtr_mile_time = qsec,
         f_v_or_straight = vs,
         f_transmission = am,
         f_gears = gear,
         f_num_carbs = carb) %>%
  mutate(f_v_or_straight = ifelse(f_v_or_straight == 0, 
                                  "V", 
                                  "Straight"),
         f_transmission = ifelse(f_transmission == 0, 
                                 "Automatic", 
                                 "Manual"),
         glm_weight = 1)
```

**`rlevel` Process** *(using `table` frequencies)*

```
proc_rlevel <- function(col) {
    agg <- df %>% group_by_at(col) %>% 
      summarise(glm_weight = sum(glm_weight)) %>%
      arrange(desc(glm_weight))

    f_ref <- df[[col]] %>% 
      as.character() %>%
      as.factor() %>%
      relevel(ref = paste(agg[[col]][1]))

    return(f_ref)
}

# REPLACING ORIGINAL f_cols WITH TWO WAY PIPES
df[grep("f_", names(df))] %<>% 
  names() %>%
  setNames(identity(.)) %>%
  map_df(proc_rlevel)
```

**Review Changes**

```
# ORIGINAL LEVELS
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("f_")) %>%
  map_df(as.factor) %>%
  map(levels)
# $f_cylinders
# [1] "4" "6" "8"
# 
# $f_v_or_straight
# [1] "Straight" "V"       
# 
# $f_transmission
# [1] "Automatic" "Manual"   
# 
# $f_gears
# [1] "3" "4" "5"
# 
# $f_num_carbs
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "6" "8"


# ADJUSTED LEVELS
df %>% 
  select(starts_with("f_")) %>%
  map_df(as.factor) %>%
  map(levels)
# $f_cylinders
# [1] "8" "4" "6"
# 
# $f_v_or_straight
# [1] "V"        "Straight"
# 
# $f_transmission
# [1] "Automatic" "Manual"   
# 
# $f_gears
# [1] "3" "4" "5"
# 
# $f_num_carbs
# [1] "2" "1" "3" "4" "6" "8"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I’ll look at this in the next day or two.